# How to convert "[array]" to [array] in javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

Is there any way to convert `"["item1","item2"]"` to `["item1","item2"]` in javascript or jQuery?

Comment: No, because your nested quotes are not escaped.

Comment: Please post *valid* code (perhaps including a sample use case/context) - then it'll be clear if `"["item1","item2"]"` is a SyntaxError, or if the original input was JSON like `'["item1","item2"]'`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
JSON.parse('["item1","item2"]');
```

Or if you really need it to support lower IE:

```
$.parseJSON('["item1","item2"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp),

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/RqjLh/1/)**

```
str = str.replace('"[', '[').replace(']"' , ']');
```